Get the last scan date or lastUpdatedDate for a given project
I am using whitesource mend api V1.4
Is there any api that gives last updated date for a given project?
When i hit the below api -
https://app.whitesourcesoftware.com/api/v1.4
```{
  "requestType":"getAllProjects",
  "userKey": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "productToken":"yyyyyyyyyy"
}```

I get list of projectName, projectToken and projectID. Does any api provide lastUpdatedDate or last scan date?
I have a python code which does get the required date, so I am looking for underlying api details.
I am using library - ws_sdk
prd_ws = WSApp(url = settings['mend']['api_url'],
            user_key = settings['mend']['user_key'],
            token_type = 'product',
            token = prd['token'])
        
        project_list = prd_ws.get_projects()
        if len(project_list) < 1:
            continue
        project_list = sorted(project_list, key=lambda d: d['lastUpdatedDate'],reverse=True)```

get_projects() does give lastUpdatedDate, so I am looking for api which can provide me this data.

Any suggestions on this would be really helpful.



May be you can use "getProjectVitals".
Request Example:
 {
    "requestType" : "getProjectVitals",
    "userKey": "user_key", 
    "projectToken" : "project_token"
}

Response Example:
{
    "projectVitals":[
        {
            "pluginName":"fs-agent",
            "pluginVersion": "18.2.2",
            "name": "My Project",
            "token": "project_token",
            "uploadedBy": "name_of_user_who_ran_scan",
            "creationDate": "2016-01-01 12:00:00",
            "lastUpdatedDate": "2016-02-02 16:50:59"
        }
    ]
}

Details you can find here : https://docs.mend.io/bundle/api_sca/page/global_organization_product_project_api.html
